# Change MySQL's datetime into a readable piece of text in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I am storing the time a player joins my server using a datetime datatype and inserting a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. All this done in MySQL.

This will look something like this: 2014-04-14 02:15:03

However, on my website I want to display the time they join but on a more friendly way such as:

April 14, 2014 2:15CST

In a nutshell, how do I change "2014-04-14 02:15:03" into "April 14, 2014 2:15CST"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it like the following:

```
date('F d, Y H:i', strtotime($mysqlTimestamp));
```

For more details, check the PHP date function at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

With your mysql timestamp in var $datetime:

```
$formatted = date("F d, Y H:ie", $datetime);
```

Refer to [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in the PHP manual :)

Comment: Hello, this does what I want but there is only one thing wrong, it displays the time in a total different date. It turns april into December.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M %d %Y %h:%i %p') or SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'%M %d %Y %h:%i %p')
```

Comment: `'%p'` is to format to `'am'` or `'pm'`, but not the timezone string like `'CST'` or `'EDT'`.